# Para que exatamente serve o método DateTime::createFromImmutable()?

Tags: php, datetime, php-7, imutabilidade

Para que exatamente serve o método `DateTime::createFromImmutable()`?
Implementado segundo a nota de lançamento da versão 7.3.0 do PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Atendendo a solicitação](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74668), o método servirá para você criar um objeto `DateTime` a partir de um objeto `DateTimeImmutable`.

```
$immutable = new DateTimeImmutable(); // objeto imutável
$mutable = DateTime::createFromImmutable($immutable); // objeto mutável
```

Este método já havia sido criado antes e foi removido posteriormente. Ele da suporte ao que existe de forma inversa. Ou seja, criar um `DateTimeImmutable` a partir de um `DateTime` desta forma:

```
$mutable = new DateTime(); // objeto mutável
$immutable = DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($mutable); // objeto imutável
```

[Veja um exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811991/convert-datetimeimmutable-to-datetime) de como poderia ser feito antes desse método:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp($dateTimeImmutable->getTimestamp());
```